# How to detect test controls at a coordinate position during runtime using Coded UI?

Tags: c#, winforms, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I have a grid in which I need to detect the last cell, I'm trying to get the bounding rectangle values of the grid and detect the control inside near the bottom right corner.

I am looking for something like,

```
WinControl FindTestControlAtPosition(double x, double y);
```

I cannot detect control using conventional methods due to reasons.

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What platform are you targeting?  What grid are you using?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2, It's a Windows Forms grid that's being detected as a WinWindow. The UI is poor that's the reason I'm trying to detect using coordinates.